# How does iphone messages code their photo selection?

Tags: iphone, swift

I want to add something like this in my app.

[image]

Was this UIColorPicker attached in AlertView? If so, how did they do the cancel button which looks separated from the AlertView?

Any advice on how to pull off something like this would be much appreciated.

Thanks